# Reading EXIF data from Canon EOS D7 with EXIF-AS3 in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, exif

My 1st post on stackoverflow, I have used the class EXIF-AS3 (Adobe Flash CS5 and AS3) many times before and it always work, I am referring to this class:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-use-as3-to-grab-exif-data-from-a-jpg-image/
http://code.google.com/p/exif-as3/

I loop through the EXIF data to find the serial number of the camera however on the new canon I can't seem to find this serial number anywhere. Seems the serial number is stored in the MarkerNotes but I don't think the class is reading it:

```
if (exifLoader.exif.ifds.primary)
        {
            displayIFD(exifLoader.exif.ifds.primary);
        }
        if (exifLoader.exif.ifds.exif)
        {
            displayIFD(exifLoader.exif.ifds.exif);
        }
        if (exifLoader.exif.ifds.gps)
        {
            displayIFD(exifLoader.exif.ifds.gps);
        }
        if (exifLoader.exif.ifds.interoperability)
        {
            displayIFD(exifLoader.exif.ifds.interoperability);
        }
        if (exifLoader.exif.ifds.thumbnail)
        {
            displayIFD(exifLoader.exif.ifds.thumbnail);
        }
```

Any advise or way I going forward here?

Comment: UPDATE: I see that the serial numbers are stored in the namespace aus and not exif.

Comment: Hmmm, seems Adobes' namespaces are missing. For example: http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.5/docs/WebHelp/references/XMPASLib/XMPConst.htm

Comment: Mean most of the namespaces in that list go to a broken link page. Anyone know where these namespaces are now stored?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the make up of the Exif object, but I would guess that if 'MarkerNotes' is a property of the Meta information it could be accessed like so:

```
if (exifLoader.exif.ifds.markerNotes) {
  displayIFD(exifLoader.exif.ifds.markerNotes);
}
```

It appears the code is checking for a non-null value and then sending the data to a method which displays the passed in tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am now almost there it appears on the newer Canon cameras for example the Canon EOS D7 it stores both EXIF data aswell as XMP data. The Serial number is stored under the aus namespace. Hope this helps someone one day. Will mark as completed when I figure out why the XMP doesn't load on this set of pictures.

Comment: Google turns up some alternatives for extracting XMP information: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=extract+xmp+data+as3&oq=extract+xmp+data+as3&aqs=chrome.0.57.5187&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Resolved: I used the class de.qwesda.as3_xmp_file.as3_xmp_file and worked great.

Comment: [code]var fileXmp:as3_xmp_file = new as3_xmp_file(picLoad);
      var dc_exif:Namespace = XMPConst.aux;
      
      //serialNumber = fileXmp.xmp.
      if (fileXmp.xmp.dc_exif::SerialNumber != null)
      {
       serialNumber = fileXmp.xmp.dc_exif::SerialNumber
      }